# Check Tomcat 7 Version linux

Tags: linux, version, tomcat7

How do I check the version of tomcat 7 that is installed on RHEL?
I looked in the bin directory and cannot find version.sh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can publish a jsp with the following scriptlet:

```
<%= application.getServerInfo() %>
```

Or grep **catalina.out** for a line like:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
```

Or take a look at the file `org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties` inside **lib/catalina.jar**.

Just to give you 3 options ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see the names and versions of any Tomcat RPM packages that are installed:

```
$ sudo rpm -qa | grep tomcat
```