# Is there a way to check what version of Tomcat is currently running on a linux box in a shell script?

Tags: linux, tomcat, server, centos

I have multiple instances of tomcat installed on a CentOS server, is there a way programmatically (via shell script) to see what version is currently running on that server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check Tomcat 7 Version linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058052/check-tomcat-7-version-linux)

Comment: @DigvijayS Not quite, that just finds whatever one is installed.